# ZF: Zend_Form_Element_File and Zend_Form - multiple uploading. How to set num for input file?

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form

I do following code several times for multiple uploading:

```
$image = new Zend_Form_Element_File("image");
        $image->setDestination(PATH)
              ->setAttrib('multiple', true)
              ->setIsArray(true);
```

After form rendering I got this one:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" />
<input type="file" name="image[]" />
<input type="file" name="image[]" />
```

But I would like to set the num for each input like:

```
<input type="file" name="image[1]" />
<input type="file" name="image[2]" />
<input type="file" name="image[3]" />
```

Is it possible to do it using Zend_Form?

(Sub_Form doesn't suit for this task, because Zend_Form_Element_File ignore it.)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add multiple inputs, like so:

```
$this->addElement('file', 'image[0]', ...);
$this->addElement('file', 'image[1]', ...);
$this->addElement('file', 'image[2]', ...);
```

Which should produce something similar to what you want.

Essentially, just give the file element the exact name you want, including the index.

Comment: I tried it. On the output I got several <input type="file" name="image" />